# c# WCF LDAP Login Authentication

Tags: c#, ldap

I have seen a few threads about LDAP but nothing seems to help.
I am looking for the most basic thing.

I have a WCF (c#) service and the requirement is that anybody that makes a call to that service must be an authenticated windows user.

If The user is already lo9gged in (eg: is connecting from his desktop on the network) then the app should allow him to make the call, if he is however not logged in (remote connection) a windows window or something like that should pop up and request his username and password.

To clarify this will be when he is remotely calling the WCF service from a web application.

I don't need any information on the user or any settings, the rule is, if he is a windows network user, he has access.

I found a LDAP sample somewhere and this is what I got out of it:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(host);
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
connection.Bind();
```

Now if the bind works, then the user is authorised if an exception is thrown then he is not.

Now I'm pretty sure I'm on the wrong track so any help on how to accomplish my task is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if he is however not logged in (remote connection)

They will still have windows credentials.

I would suggest looking into WS-Http binding. [basicHttp vs Ws-Http](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind). It will allow you to pass the credentials to the binding object. So no matter if you are using asp.net membership for authentication or just windows authentication it can handle both very easily.

Comment: Hi, no I'm creating a WCF service which will be consumed by a browser web page. My problem is do I need to get the credentials or will windows ask for them automatically somehow? I'm just not sure how the process works.

Comment: @Pete how are you hosting the WCF service?  If you are doing so in IIS, you can set the directory to only use Windows Authentication. This way if they are already authenticated, it will pass through, otherwise it will popup a box asking for credentials.

Comment: Hi Justin, That sounds like what I want to be doing. Can you tell me what is involved on the IIS side and on my code side to do this.